# How to create multiple jenkins job for multiple folders from git repository

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 5 repositories :

> 2 of Java,1 of R, 1 of Python and last of documents

I would like to create one master repository for this combinedly as folders and would like to create jenkins jobs for these folders in a repository.

Please let me know is this possible and if yes how I should approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

You can create 5 different jenkins jobs referring to the same git repo. What will differ is the content of execution phase for each of them. Say, if you're using ant, this might look:

- **Java_1 job**: `ant -f java_1/build.xml all`
- **Doc job**: `ant -f doc/build.xml all`

*Note: this approach implies an overhead in the amount of files: each job will copy and sync-up all the repo while needing only a subset of it.*

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to to create a jenkins maven job on subfolder of git in which I have put pom.xml.

When I tried to build this job manually, it fails with below exception :

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException.

It also prints :
Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/JavaOne/workspace)

Could you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

Use [dsl plugin] (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) - just generate a job for control new jobs

Comment: Hi @user3148458. We have a few guidelines on StackOverflow designed to encourage high quality answers. I recommend you read the [guide on writing good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).